# Why do I get undefined for each index of my array when I know my values have length

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

I wrote a function that places a value to ["rows"+i] and do know that each one that I set a value has a variable. I cannot figure out why, when I take the length of each and place each as a unique index in the previously empty array has a value of undefined.

My bug would be in this part of the code; I have looked for the bug, but have not yet found it (this is not the whole code, just the part where I think the bug would be:

```
  var aLength = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    aLength[i] = window["rows2"+i].length;
  return aLength;
} // this is where my ends
console.log(width(arrays));
```

//[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

full code:

```
var arrays = [[111111, 22222, 333], [444444444, 534334, 63], [73, 83748395, 9343], [279571, 327894598571490581, 34815, 2]];
var width = function(arrayOfArrays){
  var a = arrays.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    window["array"+i] = arrays[i];
  for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
    window["rows"+i] = window["array"+i];
    window["rows"+i].reduce(function (onea, twoa){
      return window["rows2"+i] = Math.max(onea, twoa);
    }, []);
    console.log(window["rows2"+i]);
  }
  var aLength = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
    aLength[i] = window["rows2"+i].length;
  return aLength;
}
console.log(width(arrays));
//111111
//444444444
//83748395
//327894598571490560
//[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You're putting numbers into "rows2"+i not arrays. Numbers have no length property.
Also your code will break as soon as you have more than 20 elements inside that "arrays" array.

Comment: I have changed the numbers to strings and still get undefined. Thanks, @LJ_1102. What do you mean by break? And how would I fix that?

Comment: Seems to work if I add `toString()`: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lh2qba7/

Comment: It now does work with the .toString() !!! Thanks!

Comment: @JavaScriptArray well when you set window["rows"+20](i being 20) it will become window["rows20"] and then in your reduce call you're writing window["rows2" + 0](i being 0) which turns out to be window["rows20"] as well. overwriting the original value. You should read up some javascript best practices guide, this code is horrible, no offense.

Comment: @LJ_1102, is there not some way to have i be incremented by 3 to skip this problem? Thanks, though, I like criticism so that I can learn from my errors. :)

Comment: @JavaScriptArray Check out my implementation of your function, even though i dont know what its use is ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lh2qba7/1/

Comment: @LJ_1102, the use of this is in building a data table laying out program. Each array in the array of arrays is a column and I need to know the greatest length of each column to know the row length. That is where this function fits in.

Comment: @JavaScriptArray well i dont know your environment or purpose but usually you want this layouting to happen in the html+css layer of your application not javascript.